# find_by() in json data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ahoy

I am using `ahoy` gem for analytics. In the `ahoy_events` table, I have `properties` column of json data type. I want to find specific data based on that column.

Suppose I have

```
{"tag":"a","class":"bigyapan-6","page":"/client/dashboard","text":"","href":"http://www.google.com"}
```

this as data and I want to find_by class.

In the `rails c` I ran `Ahoy::Event.find_by(properties[:class]: "bigyapan-6")` and it gave me an err

```
Ahoy::Event.find_by(properties["class"]: "bigyapan-6")
SyntaxError: unexpected ')', expecting end-of-input
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a syntax error since `properties[:class]` is not a valid hash key in Ruby. To query Postgres JSON columns you need to provide the query as a string:

```
Ahoy::Event.find_by("properties ->> 'class' = 'bigyapan-6'")
```

ActiveRecord does not take a nested hash in this case like it would for an association. I doubt that ActiveRecord will ever support this since its very RBDMS specific and the type coercion thing (`->` vs `->>`) would make it really complex.

```
# this won't work.
Ahoy::Event.find_by(properties: { class: 'bigyapan-6' })
```

See:

- http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json
- http://robertbeene.com/rails-4-2-and-postgresql-9-4/

Comment: Thanks max and I will take a good look at the links that you have provided.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
Ahoy::Event.find_by properties["class"].to_sym 'bigyapan-6'
```

I think it is getting confused with string followed by :

Comment: This won't work - he's trying to query a JSON column and the above is not a hash if that is what you where aiming for.